# Toolbar cut off by Status Bar

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

My `Toolbar's` top constraint is constrained to the `parent`. However the system hasn't taken into account the status bar and therefore the `Toolbar` is being cut off:

[image]

I've seen other answers which suggest to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root view so I did that. However it did not change anything.

activity_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Home"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorToolbar"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/viewpager">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

...
```

and its accompanying `HomeActivity.kt`

```
class Home : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_home)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu)
        return true
    }
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

- try using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` inside your toolbar as
  well.

> From android and material design documentations status bar height is 24dp in every screen configuration.

- so if you couldn't find any other solution you could simply use :

  ```
          android:paddingTop="24dp"
  ```

  inside your toolbar. (or margin instead, as needed)
- one more thing could cause that using constraint layout is :

  your are making the toolbar above the view pager and not the view pager under the toolbar, try changing `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/viewpager"` from toolbar to view pager as 
  `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"`

could you post your full XML file and app theme ?

Comment: Neither `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` or  `android:paddingTop="24dp"` worked but I changed the ViewGroup from `ConstraintLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and now it works.

Comment: @Zorgan yes, it was not working because the toolbar was above the viewPager and not the viewPager under it you must pay attention to these details, try my 3rd tip

Comment: I had the same issue with the Google pixel 6 and it turns out this device has a 36dp status bar, so it's best to get the device status bar height and use it as paddingTop